# How to calculate post-buff archon damage?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have a CM wizard which is built around the archon skill. When I switch to archon form and press "I", the DPS doesn't change.

I know that the skill increases my damage by 300%. But I suppose it isn't enough to add 300% to my DPS, since archon only increases my black damage (a.k.a. non-elemental) and the DPS takes the elemental damage in to account as well.

Comment: if only blizzard would put in a pvp dummy....  at least for barbs there are online tools to calculate true dps, there's probably some floating around for wizards as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Archon converts all your damage to arcane, including the elemental damage.  The DPS increase is actually quite easy to calculate.  Take your listed DPS, multiply it by 3x for archon beam damage, or multiply it by 3.75 for improved archon beam damage.